# Why is it not possible to compare session.get with a String var in Play

Tags: java, session, playframework

```
if (session.get("bla") == "test") {} // is always false wether it is "test" or not

if (session.get("bla") == null) {} // works if it is null
```

I'm not sure what the problem is but in my 1.2.2 installation I'm not able to compare

Comment: This has nothing to do with Play or sessions... it has everything to do with Java. It's worth learning the basics of Java before using a framework which has Java at its core, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparing objects with `==` is comparing the objects' references, which means that two strings with identical values might not be the same object. In order to compare the string values, use `equals`.

```
if (session.get("blah").equals("test")) {}
```

I refer you to the [Java documentation for String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Thank you very much. My customers could be happy that my active career as a programmer is already over ;-) embarrassing